# How to solve "Application Error" in Heroku (Python)

Tags: python, django, heroku, github

I created a project in `Python-Django` framework.I deploy the project in `heroku`.

When I'm trying to use `heroku open` command on terminal, I got

```
Application Error

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: Did you "check your logs for details"?

Comment: yes..please visit the given link for my logs .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39202673/i-got-an-error-while-using-heroku-open-command

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your other question, which it seems might be a duplicate, I would suggest that you follow these steps carefully:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration#the-basics

Specifically, you need to include a procfile + the right apps in requirements.txt, installing them first using `pip install` and capturing them using `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

From the logs you posted, it seems you should start with gunicorn, but it might not be the only app you're missing.