# Heroku - Giving an Application Error Page

Tags: json, heroku, intellij-idea, package.json, progressive-web-apps

I've created a PWA that's working locally but not when I try uploading it to Heroku. Does anyone have any idea why it would give me the following error?

> Application error
>
> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

My code from my package.json file is below:

```
{
  "name": "pwatrucker",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": false,
  "description": "For logging trip data",
  "main": "bin/server",
  "keywords": [
    "spa",
    "pwa"
  ],
  "author": {
    "name": "asdf"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node bin/server"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 6.5.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "latest",
    "foobar": "^1.1.0",
    "formidable": "latest",
    "nedb": "latest"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do the logs say?

Answer (score 1):

You can try typing the command `heroku logs` into the console to show the log, which will probably say something relevant to the problem. As stated in this [thread](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1218747), there can be a number of reasons and the advice to check those logs will help. Things to watch out for are analyzing what may be different on heroku than with your local copy. Simple things are like: is the type of database the same, are you trying to upload a file when the app is not configured to work with external storage, is there something in your local db that you are so used to having set that might not on the one heroku is looking at etc. You may also check this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39209671/how-to-solve-application-error-in-heroku-python) which might help.